# How to get private cluster to finalize non-vote TX?

Tags: local-cluster

I have a private cluster running on two remote rigs. One is the bootstrap validator that is created with genesis and is funded. I can get it to vote using `--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader`  but only vote TX not economic TX. Any economic TX (like `airdrop` or `transfer`) result in a TX that fails to finalize.

How do I get my cluster out of what appears to be a `vote-only` mode?

`sol@solval-local:~$ solana transfer 2fFLVWNqS8rSyVAY7YgwtqfAXv2j9xtnurJJkebrNwSL 100 -k ~/bootstrap-validator-keypair.json --allow-unfunded-recipient _ [0/1] Finalizing transaction 5MypRxRJbmfLvEDQRR9F2rGmXRdH65U1QKEGquWWhagWSUJ9syBtquKz7Vh3HQnvs2KRs5DJjxzvUXkeFRhAu9rZ`
`Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds`

But I do have balance:
`sol@solval-local:~$ solana balance ~/bootstrap-validator-keypair.json 4999.7369125 SOL`

`Config File: /home/sol/.config/solana/cli/config.yml RPC URL: http://x.x.x.x:12001 WebSocket URL: ws://x.x.x.x:12002/ (computed) Keypair Path: /home/sol/bootstrap-validator-keypair.json Commitment: confirmed`

```
Ledger location: /home/sol/genesis-ledger/
Identity: nvBtL5NBCx6GhKnHi6kET4SD3piTYdQPGxkNHryrFAD
Genesis Hash: BfqjowRCX5rtPejwVhbpiXT6gh6avzGCVKNyZzfK8wGY
Version: 1.13.7
Shred Version: 1450
Gossip Address: x.x.x.x:12000
TPU Address: x.x.x.x:11999
JSON RPC URL: http://x.x.x.x:12001
_ 00:21:03 | Processed Slot: 103803 | Confirmed Slot: 103802 | Finalized Slot: 103771 | Full Snapshot Slot: 103006 | Incremental Snapshot Slot: 103606 | Transactions: 103791 | _4999.740525000
```

```
Ledger location: /home/sol/ledger
Identity: 2fFLVWNqS8rSyVAY7YgwtqfAXv2j9xtnurJJkebrNwSL
Genesis Hash: BfqjowRCX5rtPejwVhbpiXT6gh6avzGCVKNyZzfK8wGY
Version: 1.13.7
Shred Version: 1450
Gossip Address: y.y.y.y:9997
TPU Address: y.y.y.y:8021
JSON RPC URL: http://y.y.y.y:9998
⠋ 00:36:33 | Processed Slot: 104098 | Confirmed Slot: 104097 | Finalized Slot: 104066 | Full Snapshot Slot: 100005 | Incremental Snapshot Slot: 104006 | Transactions: 104086 | ◎0.000000000
```

```
sol@solval-local:~$ solana gossip
IP Address      | Identity                                     | Gossip | TPU   | RPC Address           | Version | Feature Set
----------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-------+-----------------------+---------+----------------
x.x.x.x  | nvBtL5NBCx6GhKnHi6kET4SD3piTYdQPGxkNHryrFAD  | 12000  | 11999 | x.x.x.x:12001  | 1.13.7  | 1775889670
y.y.y.y  | 2fFLVWNqS8rSyVAY7YgwtqfAXv2j9xtnurJJkebrNwSL | 9997   | 8021  | y.y.y.y:9998   | 1.13.7  | 1775889670
Nodes: 2
```

```
sol@solval-local:~$ solana validators
   Identity                                      Vote Account                            Commission  Last Vote        Root Slot     Skip Rate  Credits  Version            Active Stake
_ nvBtL5NBCx6GhKnHi6kET4SD3piTYdQPGxkNHryrFAD   2EquiqgDgNYhjAHyyCnkN2QjYLcA5iCLdqa51WTovig2  100%     105933 (  0)     105902 (  0)   0.03%     7660   1.13.7      4999.997717120 SOL (100.00%)

Average Stake-Weighted Skip Rate: 0.03%
Average Unweighted Skip Rate:     0.03%

Active Stake: 4999.99771712 SOL

Stake By Version:
1.13.7  -    1 current validators (100.00%)
```

Comment: Everything seems reasonable, so I wonder if there's a networking issue going on. Can you try just running a `solana-test-validator` on one machine first and make sure that you can send transactions to that? If that works, then there's probably something going on with the command line args. Can you post the full args that you're using to spin up the two validators?